# Did 25 people die because of H1N1 vaccine of 1976?

Tags: vaccines, flu

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_swine_flu)

> The 1976 swine flu outbreak, also known as the swine flu fiasco, or
>   the swine flu debacle, was a strain of H1N1 influenza virus that
>   appeared in 1976. Infections were only detected from January 19 to
>   February 9, and were not found outside Fort Dix. The outbreak is most
>   remembered for the mass immunization that it prompted in the United
>   States. The strain itself killed one person and hospitalized 13.
>   However, side-effects from the vaccine are thought to have caused five
>   hundred cases of Guillain–Barré syndrome and 25 deaths.

However, allegedly this has been recently revisited and contested. For example:

> Whether or not any of the antecedents had a causal relationship to GBS
>   was, and remains, unclear. When cases of GBS were identified among
>   recipients of the swine flu vaccines, they were, of course, well
>   covered by the press. Because GBS cases are always present in the
>   population, the necessary public health questions concerning the cases
>   among vaccine recipients were "Is the number of cases of GBS among
>   vaccine recipients higher than would be expected? And if so, are the
>   increased cases the result of increased surveillance or a true
>   increase?" Leading epidemiologists debated these points, but the
>   consensus, based on the intensified surveillance for GBS (and other
>   conditions) in recipients of the vaccines, was that the number of
>   cases of GBS appeared to be an excess.

source: [*"Reflections on the 1976 Swine Flu Vaccination Program"*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3291400/) in Emerging Infectious Diseases journal.

Although Wikipedia provides some references, to prevent getting an answer that simply repeats them, let me clarify that I am not happy with them because they are press articles, rather than peer reviewed papers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Deaths following vaccination: What does the evidence show?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4599698/) *Vaccine* (2015) vol. 33, pages 3288-3292:

> ...an unexpectedly high number of cases of Guillain-Barré syndrome were reported in vaccinated individuals. The vaccine was estimated to have caused approximately one Guillain-Barré syndrome case per 100,000 persons vaccinated [17], resulting in 53 deaths [18]. As a result of the association between the 1976 swine flu vaccine and Guillain-Barré syndrome, this condition is closely monitored every influenza season as part of the influenza vaccine safety monitoring in the United States.

Reference 17 is [Guillain-Barre syndrome following vaccination in the National Influenza Immunization Program, United States, 1976--1977](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/463869). *American Journal of Epidemiology* vol. 110, pages 105-123. The abstract of which says:

> This surveillance uncovered a total of 1098 patients with onset of GBS from October 1, 1976, to January 31, 1977, from all 50 states, District of Columbia, and Puerto Rico. A total of 532 patients had recently received an A/New Jersey influenza vaccination prior to their onset of GBS (vaccinated cases), and 15 patients received a vaccination after their onset of GBS. Five hundred forty-three patients had not been recently vaccinated with A/New Jersey influenza vaccine and the vaccination status for 8 was unknown. Epidemiologic evidence indicated that many cases of GBS were related to vaccination. When compared to the unvaccinated population, the vaccinated population had a significantly elevated attack rate in every adult age group. The estimated attributable risk of vaccine-related GBS in the adult population was just under one case per 100,000 vaccinations.

The Center for Disease Control similarly states on their [Guillain-Barré syndrome and Flu Vaccine](http://www.cdc.gov/flu/protect/vaccine/guillainbarre.htm) page:

> In 1976 there was a small increased risk of GBS following vaccination with an influenza vaccine made to protect against a swine flu virus. The increased risk was approximately 1 additional case of GBS per 100,000 people who got the swine flu vaccine.

Reference 18 is The vaccine controversy: the history, use and safety of vaccinations. Westport, CT: Praeger publishers; 2005.